Instanton partition function: Why don't self-dual connections contribute?
For a gauge theory, one can split the partition function
$$ Z = \int [DA] e^{-S[A]} = \int [DA_{inst}] \int [D\delta A] e^{-S[A_{inst}+\delta A]}. $$
Using the expansion
$$ S[A_{inst}+\delta A] = S[A_{inst}] + \sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{\delta^n S[A_{inst}]}{\delta A^n} \delta A^n = \frac{8\pi^2}{g^2}|k| - i\theta k + S_{fluc}[\delta A], $$
this becomes
\begin{equation} \label{eq:a}
Z = \int [DA_{inst}] e^{-\frac{8\pi^2}{g^2}|k[A_{inst}]|+i\theta k[A_{inst}]} \int [D\delta A] e^{-S_{fluc}[\delta A]} = Z_{inst} Z_{pert}. \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
The first factor is the instanton partition function. In $N=2$ supersymmetric $SU(n)$ gauge theory, Nekrasov (arXiv:hep-th/0206161) used equivariant localization to compute this integral $Z_{inst}$ as a function of Coulomb moduli and parameters of $\Omega$-deformation. His definition is:
$$ Z_{inst} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k \int_{M(n,k)} 1 $$
where $q = e^{-\frac{8\pi^2}{g^2}+i\theta}$ and $M(n,k)$ is a resolved version of the instanton moduli space. I don't understand where this definition comes from: Starting with the integral (1), shouldn't we rather have
$$ Z_{inst} = \int [DA_{inst}] e^{-\frac{8\pi^2}{g^2}|k[A_{inst}]|+i\theta k[A_{inst}]} = \sum_{k < 0} \bar q^k \int_{M(n,k)} 1 + \sum_{k \geq 0} q^k \int_{M(n,k)} 1, $$
with instantons with $k < 0$ (self-dual connections, $k \geq 0$ is anti-self-dual) also contributing?
Also, what parts of the derivation of Nekrasov's form of the instanton partition function depend on the $N=2$ setting?

Is your question how equivariant localization leads to the expression beneath (1) ? If your question is why negative k instantons do not contribute then the answer is that we start with a bundle on a superspace where a global section  is either $F^+$ or $F^-$. So we consider either instantons or anti-instantons not both.

The expression beneath (1) comes from dividing the integral in (1) into a sum over the different instanton sectors, right?
Yes, my question was mainly why negative $k$ doesn't contribute. Do you have a reference for this? Does this also happen in $N=1$?

Yes and no. The instanton moduli space is the space of BPS states in super Yang-Mills and those are fixed points of a group action on some superspace. The instantons represent cohomology classes in the chiral ring of the theory. The instanton moduli space is basicly the zero-section of some bundle and a localization locus. On this space in return acts another product group and we can use localization again to reduce the instanton partition function to a sum over these fixed points. It is all explained in Nekrasov's paper but if you want I can try to explain it in an answer. Only for $N=2$

So you say that to get from $(1)$ to $\sum q^k \int 1$ one applies localization. I guess this means the moduli spaces are the components of the fixed point manifold for some action? If you can find the time to write an answer that'd be great (I'm a maths Master's student btw, I understand basic QFT but not much past that).
I do know how localization is applied to the integrals $\int_{M(n,k)} 1$, whose fixed point set is discrete and parametrized by partitions. So no need to explain that part. I really just want to understand why $Z_{inst} = \sum_{k \geq 0} q^k \int_{M(n,k)} 1$.

Okay lets see. Let $P$ be some principal $G$-bundle over a smooth four-dimensional manifold $X$. We start with the space of fields, which is the product of bosonic fields and their superpartners
$$\mathcal G=\mathcal A(G) \times \Omega^0(X,ad\,G) \times \Omega^*(A(G) \times \Omega^0(X,ad\,G))=\mathcal B \times \mathcal F$$
$\mathcal A$ is the space of $G$-connections flat at infinity. The other thing we need is the space of self-dual fields and covariantly constant sections $\phi \in \Omega^0(X,ad\,G)$
$$\mathcal M_G=\{(A,\phi) \in \mathcal B\, \big |\, F^+=0,\nabla_A\phi=0\}/\mathcal R(P)$$
The space of sections $\phi$ is identified with the Lie-algebra of automorphisms $\mathcal R(P)$ of $P$ trivial at infinity. Now we consider the bundle $\pi : \mathcal E \rightarrow \mathcal B/\mathcal R(P)$
$$\mathcal E=\mathcal B \, \times_{\mathcal R(P)}(\Omega^{2+}(X,ad\,G) \oplus \,\Omega^1(X,ad\,G)) $$
By Poincarè duality we have the pushforward in cohomology $\pi_* :H^*(\mathcal E)\rightarrow H^*(\mathcal B/\mathcal R(P))$ called the Thom isomorphism as well as the Thom class $T(\mathcal E) :=\pi_*^{-1}(1) \in H^*(\mathcal E)$. Notice that a section of $\mathcal E$ is
$$s(A,\phi)=(F^+,\nabla_A\phi)$$
and therefore that $\mathcal M_G$ is the zero-locus of this section. By standard theorems we have now that the pullback $s^*(T(\mathcal E))$ of the Thom class along the section is the Euler class $e(\mathcal E)$.  It satisfies the localization property
$$\int_{\mathcal B/\mathcal R(P)}s^*(T(\mathcal E))\, \wedge \alpha=\int_{\mathcal M_G} i^*\alpha,$$
whereby $\alpha$ is a form on $\mathcal B$, or in physics terms a gauge-invariant observable $\alpha=e^{-S}\mathcal O$ and $i: \mathcal M_G \hookrightarrow \mathcal B/\mathcal R(P)$. The class $s^*(T(\mathcal E))$ is the Poincaré-dual of this inclusion. The left side is basicly already a prototypical partition function and it is mathematically the Mathai-Quillen representative of the Thom class. Furthermore,  for such an inclusion the  Thom class is isomorphic to the Thom class of the normal bundle of $\mathcal M_G$ in $\mathcal B/\mathcal R(P)$. What one wants to do is localization on the full space $\mathcal G$, so-called supersymmetric localization. Here the generators $\mathcal Q$ of the supersymmetry define a chiral ring $H^*(\mathcal G,\mathcal Q)$. One applies the $\mathcal R$-equivariant localization to the space $\mathcal G$. The localization locus is the space of BPS-states or $\mathcal Q$-fixed-points. Under good conditions these are irreducible connections with $\phi=0$. The zero locus is the instanton moduli space $\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)$. Notice that $k\geq 0$ since we considered a specific bundle $\mathcal E$. We may also choose $F^-$. The equivariant Thom isomorphism
$$\pi_*:H^*_{\mathcal R(P)}(\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)) \rightarrow H^*(\mathcal G,\mathcal Q)$$
The reson for these two different viewpoints is that there exists a twisted version of the super Yang-Mills theory also called cohomological Yang-Mills or Donaldson-Witten theory, where one does the second method.
In this case the partition function localizes to a weighted sum of characteristic classes of the bundle $P$ which only depend on topological data
$$\mathcal Z=\sum^\infty_{k=0}q^k \int_{\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)} \mathcal C $$
The integral is understood as a pushforward map in equivariant cohomology. What Nekrasov did is to realize that additionally to the gauge-group there is an action of $GL(2)$ on $\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)$. This comes from the identification of instantons with torsion-free sheaves on $\mathbb {CP}^2$, wher $GL(2)$ rotates the $\mathbb C^2$. Using now T-equivariant localization the Mathai-Quillen representative is a weighted-sum of the equivariant volumes of the instanton moduli space. (The equation underneath (1)). This can be further expressed as an integral over the inverse of the $T$-equivarant Euler characteristic classes of the tangent bundle of the $T$-fixed-points in $\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)$ by standard localization theorems. In particular the pushforward $f_*:H^*_{T}(\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)) \rightarrow H^*_T(pt)$ is equivalent to the integration of a class $\mathcal C$ in the $T$-equivariant cohomology of $\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)$. So when Nekrasov writes $\int_{\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)} 1$ he means $f_*1$ in $H^*_T(pt)$. This is the integration of the equivariant volume of $\mathcal M_{G,k}(X)$.
Due to the fact that we are dealing with a Kähler manifold and $T$ acts in a Hamiltonian way, we can use the Dustermaat-Heckamn formula (expression 1.4 in Nekrasovs paper). The fact that these fixed-points are given by $N$-vectors of partitions can now be used to evaluate this partition function, which is rly surprising. Even more surprising that the partition function is a conformal block of Whittaker vectors of an affine W-algebra but that is a different story.
EDIT: I do not know how familiar you are with localization in geometry but it might be helpful to know that $H^*_T(pt)=H^*(BT)$, where $BT$ is the classifying space.
